# Why did Reiko choose to be a teacher at class 3-3?

Tags: another

Reiko was a student at class 3-3 15 years ago. She knew about the curse. Why did she become a teacher at class 3-3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although not explained explicitly, it is implied that she became upset when her best friend died when she was a student in Yomiama high school and she wanted to know the root cause of the curse.   Later when her sister died (whom she idolized the most), she held the idea that the death is related to the curse ([atleast this is what was implied in the show](https://another.fandom.com/wiki/Ritsuko_Sakakibara)) and thus she became a teacher in that school.

> She seemed to get very upset whenever someone talked about the incident 15 years ago, when she was in the 9th grade in class 3. Also, at that time she didn't believe in the curse until her best friend, Ryoko, died. When she saw that day by day, more classmates and their relatives are dying, *she wanted to find out how to stop the calamity, asking Mr. Chibiki about it. Reiko claimed that her eldest sister, Ritsuko, was the woman she admired the most and also her idol and that she was very happy when she came to Yomiyama.* She loved her very much, and Reiko frequently visited her at the hospital after she gave birth to Kouichi. Also, before Kouichi came to live with her she claimed the fact that she would protect him, as Ritsuko said that she will protect him shortly before she died
>
> <sub>https://another.fandom.com/wiki/Reiko_Mikami</sub>